# regular expression to match certain special characters

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I need to do a reg expression match containing some special characters like

**( , ) , \ , / , $ , # , % , @ , ***

I want to match all the possible characters so i could remove them by blank space. Is it possible by a single expression ?

Comment: What language ? What did you try ? What doesn't work ?

Comment: What do you mean by the last paragraph?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the special characters? Or detect when they are present?

Comment: i m trying to replace them by blank space when present. I am using as3.

Comment: @Lepidosteus i m using as3. i could replace one character as  newLine.replace( /\$/gm, "");

Comment: How about do the opposite, instead of dissallowing chars put only allowed, this way you are sure that only allowed are there and you haven't forget to exclude something e.g. `var allowed:RegExp = /[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/g;` then you can use it in the same way as Burnzy proposed (replace).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify language, here's how you would do it in javascript

```
var crazyString = "bla/$ bla @ me *";
var sanitized = crazyString.replace(/[()\\\/$#%@*]/g, ' ');
```

In regex `[]` is a character set. It means **any character in the following set**. There is also some special character sets such as `[a-z]` which means any lower case character from a to z. You can as well do something with number ranges with `[3-9]` which only match a number from 3 to 9.

Please note that in those two special character sets, hyphen is a special character, if you would be looking to match, let's say only letters and hyphen you could use the following `[a-z-]`

Answer (score 1):

replace `[()\\/$#%@*]` with  (space)

`[()\\/$#%@*]` is the regex you are looking for.

Comment: For those using C style languages that would be "[()\\\\/$#%@*]"